# give duration to addClass/removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to set up a few add/removeClass functions, of the same class, depending on what's happening. It works, but the problem is one (the function binded to loadstart) needs a duration of a different length than the other two, so putting `transition-duration` doesn't work.

I've looked around for a way, but they're not working.the css is

```
#MyT{
    height:786px;
    width:1024px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    margin-left:-8px; 
    margin-top:-16px;
}
.clear {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

and the script is

```
 $('#myVid').bind("ended", function(){  
      $('#MyT').removeClass('clear');
    });



 $('#myVid').bind("loadstart", function(){          
      $('#MyT').removeClass('clear');
    });



 $('#myVid').bind("playing", function(){  
      $('#MyT').addClass('clear');
    });
```

can I get some help please?

Comment: can u pls elaborate "one needs a different duration than the other two"

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking for, maybe you are after `addClass` (`removeClass`) from jQuery UI? http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/

Comment: @FelixKling i want to be able to set specific durations for them...

Comment: That's what the second argument is doing. Have you actually had a look the link? Or am I still not getting it?

Comment: @FelixKlingsorry added comment then looked at link. This works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** EDIT:

try something like: `setTimeout("$('#MyT').removeClass('clear')", 500);`

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

The jQuery's **Delay** function might help with this.

More details here: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: `removeClass` is not an animation method though and won't be queued by default.

Comment: Thanks, @Felix Klin, I did not test it out, I just recalled the function and thought it might have something to try. The same concept could be applied I guess by using the javascript function **setTimeout** instead